# ubuntu - use a disk without paritioning it?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, fdisk

i added a hard disk to my ubuntu install today. i previously had 2 hard disks. i added a 3rd today. The 3rd harddisk is sdc

running `lsblk` it looks like

```
sda      8:0    0    35G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0  32.5G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0    30G  0 disk /mnt/sdb
sdc      8:32   0    30G  0 disk
└─sdc1   8:33   0    30G  0 part /mnt/sdc1
```

sdb is in use. i can go to `/mnt/sdb` and do an `ls` and see the contents.

**How did I set this up so it doesn't have a parition?**

e.g. if i do `fdisk /dev/sdb/`

```
# fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

The old ext4 signature will be removed by a write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x7eb7e7a3.
```

it does see an old ext4 sig (?) but it also says no recognized partition table.

I have no idea what I did there and if it's something i should revisit/fix.

Comment: You're not explaining what you actually want to do. You can run `mkfs.<whatever>` on `/dev/sdb`, but you are advised to create at least 1 partition. Running `fsck` will wipe what is already there, as such, it matter not a jot.

Comment: Is the 3rd disk `sdb` or `sdc`? Anyway, you just didn't format or partition the disk. Follow this [example tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-disk-format/).

Comment: @Bib thanks. i think mkfs is what i did. my ask was trying to figure out how i created a filesystem without a parition. i guess i just skipped the partitioning step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bib says in a comment above...

Creating a filesystem on a bare disk, without partitioning, is fully possible; you might even succeed overwriting a previous partition table/actions (clearing it? I have never tried that).

But then, I would not be surprised if there is at least one OS in the world that *might **not*** be 'happy' with it.

That would be:

```
$ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb
```

Comment: seeing the `mkfs` command makes me think this is what i did. i don't have anything critical on this hd right now so maybe i'll wipe and re-create with a paritition.